# notepad++ regex - add multi perfix

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to add a multi prefix to each 1 line. example:

```
Username1
Username2
Username3
Username4
etc..
```

I want to add the follow to these usernames.

```
Passwd1
Passwd2
Passwd3
```

Final results:

```
Username1:Passwd1
Username1:Passwd2
Username1:Passwd3
Username2:Passwd1
Username2:Passwd2
Username2:Passwd3
Username3:Passwd1
Username3:Passwd2
Username3:Passwd3

etc...
```

I've tried to do:

```
Search: ^(.*)$
Replace with: \1:Passwd1
```

but it add only 1 passwd.

Thank you,
regards.

how to add multi passwords?

Comment: Please explain the rules of the substitution. Provide the real sample data in the question. Add the expected result.

Comment: Try replacing `^\w+$` (or `^.+$`) with `$0:Passwd1\r\n$0:Passwd2\r\n$0:Passwd3`.

Answer (score 1):

Find with `(Username\d)`

Replace with `\1:Passwd1\n\1:Passwd2\n\1:Passwd3`

Before replacement:

```
Username1
Username2
Username3
Username4
```

After replacement:

[image: After replacement]

If you have variable passwords you can edit them accordingly in replacement string.

Comment: Thank you for your support, but it's Not working shown error: Replace: No occurrence was found.

Comment: Worked for me. Check the image I just added.

Comment: Username was an example, what i have is a file with random words. So how to make it work with random words. example: https://gyazo.com/cae4aaf4287b3ec99a724d8ca46d21f3

Comment: @Tcode: You should add this info to your question with necessary data in plain text.